# How to open link from iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, href

I have this:

```
<td onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com/';"> </td>
```

The problem is that I have this inside an iframe, so onclick it opens in the iframe. How do I open this link on the parent page instead of the iframe?

(Is there a way to do this with one js script for all the links on the page?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.parent.location.href='http://www.google.com/';
```

and if you want to reload the top most window:

```
window.top.location.href='http://www.google.com/';
```

Comment: Is there a difference in 'speed' between 'top' and 'parent' ?

Comment: @Youss, I don't think there will be any difference in speed. There is a difference in the behavior though.

Answer (score 1):

one way to do this with on js script for all the links on the page is to add onClick event on the links when the page is loaded. here is a quick code. put this code in a file and put it in an iframe.

```
<html>
<script>
function openInParent() {
  window.parent.location = this.href;
  return false;
}

function doload () {
  // loop through all links in the page to add onclick event
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName ('a');
  for(i in links) {
    links[i].onclick = openInParent;
  }
}

window.onload = doload;
</script>
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```